# I have deleted my C:\Windows\System32\spp folder. Is there any way to restore it?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-activation, software-activation

It seems a bit weird but as the title says, I accidentally deleted the folder permanently (C:\Windows\System32\spp). Is there any way to restore it, because these commands does not seem to check that folder:

```
DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
sfc /scannow
```

I am trying not to do a full system reinstall. I know I can move it from existing install on different PC, but I am asking if there is any way to restore it without having another Windows PC.

I am using Windows 10 LTSC 2019 (1809)

Comment: No; You will have to perform a full reinstall.

Comment: @Ramhound *I am trying not to do a full system reinstall*

Comment: @Ramhound Already tried restoring even from install.wim, but the files are generated dynamically at installation and are not contained there.

Comment: You might try a Windows 10 Repair Install. This is not a reinstall of Windows. Use the option to Keep Everything initially.  Go to the Media Creation link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and run in place